# "Refresh All" still trying to refresh old deleted connections in excel workbook

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook to which I've added several external XML data connections. Several of these connections didnt work and I removed them. Now when I hit "Refresh all" it still tries to connect to the connections that I have removed and gives me an error. Is there anyway I can get rid of those permenantly so this error doesnt keep coming up?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to delete the XML maps as well. To do this, go to Developer Tab > Sources > XML Maps
Then delete them